# Delphi v.Word - how to set Word dialog argument from Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word

In VBA I can use:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).Select
With Dialogs(wdDialogFormFieldOptions)
  .Name = 'ojejku'
  .Execute
End With
```

but in Delphi (XE5)?

```
WordApplication.ActiveDocument.FormFields.Item(1).Select;
// WordApplication.Dialogs.Item(wdDialogFormFieldOptions).Name := 'MyName'; // This not working
WordApplication.Dialogs.Item(wdDialogFormFieldOptions).Execute;
```

Comment: As Christine mentioned below, there is no Name property on Dialogs, so even the VBA options should fail. It is likely that you disabled the Error handler in VBA. If you enter the provided VBA code the .Name line will light up red due to the non existing Name property.

Comment: +1 to offset unfounded downvote. @Maarten, obviously the VBA code works, see wdDialogFormFieldOptions in the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836540.aspx), and [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/AssignNameToFmFld.htm) is an example.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to use late binding where the signature of the type library does not match what you are supposed to be able to do. You can switch to IDispatch dispatching any time, see the second snippet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40694111/243614).

Comment: @Maarten please be carefully with the "s": There is a collection named "Dialogs", when you refer the "item" Method (as he did in the question, he refers to a dialog object) you get an object called "Dialog" (no "s"). But anayway both do not have a property called "Name". I do not know what VBA does, but the MS documentation is clear and you should follow it. I would not recommend late binding because it makes error tracking very time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Because the Dialog Object has no property called "name". See the MS reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840578.aspx)

Comment: See my comment to the question.